# Is there a TOS episode where Captain Kirk wears a red shirt?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

My question is as simple as the title gets.

I haven't finished watching TOS yet, so if I'll notice such occurrence I'll make sure to update here.

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9rrg45qZQ70/UcD6vx1DEnI/AAAAAAAAA-w/ZG1YpZaCqCU/s1600/captainkirk.jpg

Comment: @Richard ... was going to show nearly the [same picture](http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/8400000/Captain-Kirk-james-t-kirk-8476028-1200-1750.jpg). I thought he might have worn one in *Mirror, Mirror*, but it was a gold vest there, not red.

Answer (score 7):

TOS Episode, no.

(but)

In the 1971 annual, Kirk's uniform was red. No explanation was given for the colour change.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  And Scotty is wearing blue!

Comment: Wow, what a pose!

Answer (score 1):

Not as any part of his regular duties.  I am also almost certain that he never did as any sort of disguise.

Comment: I only recall gold, green(ish) and an occasional zoot suit.

Answer (score 0):

Red shirts (uniforms) signified engineering & security; blue was science & medicine, and gold was command.

If the green variant was ever explained, I missed that one.  But since we always saw Kirk in a command position, never as an engineer or science position, we always saw him wearing gold -- at least in the original TV series.

Comment: In TOS, command used green shirts.  However, the color of these wasn't apparent through the color TV of the period so they appeared gold.

The green of the casual and dress shirts Kirk uses in the show comes through much better.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(mid_2260s-early_2270s)